# SQL Server - Subselect returns more than 1 row. How to properly select all?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Relevant to this question is the table "tAttributes"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tAttributes](
    [GUID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Attribute] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RelatedGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [LevelLow] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [LevelHigh] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [LevelStep] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [AttributeLevel] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [AutoselectGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [CompanySystem] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PeopleSystem] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SearchSystem] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Populate] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Synonyms] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [TimeEntered] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserEnteredGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [TimeUpdated] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserUpdatedGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [UpdateHistory] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Stamp] [timestamp] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tAttributes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_AttributeRelatedGUID] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Attribute] ASC,
    [RelatedGUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

It has attributes for example:

```
GUID|Attribute|RelatedGUID|....
1   | Val1    | 2         |
3   | Val2    | NULL      |
4   | val3    | 5         |
```

Val1 is an Attribute, Val2 where RelatedGUID is NULL is a Category

Live example, i.e:

```
F0F9EA32-C3AC-48A9-B6BE-09807B720818| gaming | 09E898CC-5DE2-4664-B9B2-14F17FBC37DB
32B74398-83C9-4225-81E2-0A1CB6C67954 | Function skills | NULL
```

"gaming" is an Attribute

"Function skills" is a Category

How do I subselect it so, that in the column Attributes I will have only attributes, values which have RelatedGUID different than NULL and in column Categories, categories, values which have RelatedGUID eqaul to NULL?

I have this query:

```
select tsearch.Description,

tcompany.CompanyName,
tcompany.GUID as CompanyGuid,
tcompanylocation.LocationName,
tsearchtype.SearchType,
tsearchresult.searchresult,
tpeople.GUID as PersonPlacedGuid,
tpeople.LastName As PersonPlacedLName,
tpeople.Firstname As PersonPlacedFName,
tsearch.SearchNotes,
( select tpeople.Firstname  from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.RepresentativeGUID) as repfirstname, 
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.RepresentativeGUID) as replastname,
tsearch.RepresentativeGUID as RepGuid,
tposition.Position as backgroundposition,
tdepartment.Department as backgrounddepartment,
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.ReferredByGUID) as referredbylastname,
( select tpeople.FirstName from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.ReferredByGUID) as referredbylastname,
tsearch.ReferredByGUID as PersonwhorefferedGuid,
( select tcompany.CompanyName from tCompany where tCompany.guid=tSearch.PlacedFromGUID) as placedfrom,
tinstantstatustype.InstantStatus,
tWorkbench.WorkbenchName,
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tInstantStatus.PeopleGUID) as Candlastname,
( select tpeople.FirstName from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tInstantStatus.PeopleGUID) as candFirstname,
tInstantStatus.ForClientNotes,
tinstantstatus.InstantStatusNotes as InstanttatusNotesSummary,
( select top 1 tAttributes.Attribute from tAttributes where tAttributes.RelatedGUID is not NUll ) as Attributes,
( select top 1 tAttributes.Attribute from tAttributes where tAttributes.RelatedGUID is  NUll ) as Categories


from tSearch


full join tCompany on tsearch.CompanyGUID = tcompany.guid
full join tcompanylocation on tcompanylocation.guid= tcompany.LocationGUID
full join tSearchType on tsearchtype.GUID = tSearch.SearchTypeGUID
full join tSearchResult on tSearchResult.GUID = tsearch.SearchResultGUID
full join tPeople on tPeople.GUID = tsearch.PlacedGUID
full join tPosition on tPosition.GUID = tsearch.PositionGUID
full join tDepartment on tdepartment.GUID = tsearch.DepartmentGUID
full join tInstantStatus on tInstantStatus.SearchGUID = tSearch.guid
full join tInstantStatusType on tInstantStatusType.GUID = tInstantStatus.InstantStatusGUID 
full join tWorkbench on tWorkbench.SearchGUID=tsearch.GUID
full join tSearchCluendex on tSearchCluendex.CPSGUID=tsearch.GUID
full join tAttributes on tAttributes.GUID=tSearchCluendex.AttributeGUID
```

Here I did it using "top 1" trick, but the problem is there are more Categories than 1, so the "top 1" is a not complete solution:

```
( select top 1 tAttributes.Attribute from tAttributes where tAttributes.RelatedGUID is not NUll ) as Attributes,
( select top 1 tAttributes.Attribute from tAttributes where tAttributes.RelatedGUID is  NUll ) as Categories
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**

Based on @Shungo hints.

This also does not work:

```
select tsearch.Description,

tcompany.CompanyName,
tcompany.GUID as CompanyGuid,
tcompanylocation.LocationName,
tsearchtype.SearchType,
tsearchresult.searchresult,
tpeople.GUID as PersonPlacedGuid,
tpeople.LastName As PersonPlacedLName,
tpeople.Firstname As PersonPlacedFName,
tsearch.SearchNotes,
( select tpeople.Firstname  from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.RepresentativeGUID) as repfirstname, 
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.RepresentativeGUID) as replastname,
tsearch.RepresentativeGUID as RepGuid,
tposition.Position as backgroundposition,
tdepartment.Department as backgrounddepartment,
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.ReferredByGUID) as referredbylastname,
( select tpeople.FirstName from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.ReferredByGUID) as referredbylastname,
tsearch.ReferredByGUID as PersonwhorefferedGuid,
( select tcompany.CompanyName from tCompany where tCompany.guid=tSearch.PlacedFromGUID) as placedfrom,
tinstantstatustype.InstantStatus,
tWorkbench.WorkbenchName,
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tInstantStatus.PeopleGUID) as Candlastname,
( select tpeople.FirstName from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tInstantStatus.PeopleGUID) as candFirstname,
tInstantStatus.ForClientNotes,
tinstantstatus.InstantStatusNotes as InstanttatusNotesSummary,
( select a1.Attribute from tAttributes where tAttributes.RelatedGUID is not NUll ) as Attributes,
( select a1.Attribute from tAttributes where tAttributes.RelatedGUID is  NUll ) as Categories


from tSearch


full join tCompany on tsearch.CompanyGUID = tcompany.guid
full join tcompanylocation on tcompanylocation.guid= tcompany.LocationGUID
full join tSearchType on tsearchtype.GUID = tSearch.SearchTypeGUID
full join tSearchResult on tSearchResult.GUID = tsearch.SearchResultGUID
full join tPeople on tPeople.GUID = tsearch.PlacedGUID
full join tPosition on tPosition.GUID = tsearch.PositionGUID
full join tDepartment on tdepartment.GUID = tsearch.DepartmentGUID
full join tInstantStatus on tInstantStatus.SearchGUID = tSearch.guid
full join tInstantStatusType on tInstantStatusType.GUID = tInstantStatus.InstantStatusGUID 
full join tWorkbench on tWorkbench.SearchGUID=tsearch.GUID
full join tSearchCluendex on tSearchCluendex.CPSGUID=tsearch.GUID
full join tAttributes on tAttributes.GUID=tSearchCluendex.AttributeGUID
LEFT JOIN tAttributes AS a1 ON a1.GUID=tSearchCluendex.AttributeGUID
```

Returns:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

**Update 2:**

Looks better, unfortunately Attributes and Categories have the same value. I want Attributes to have values where RelatedGUID is not NULL and Categories where RelatedGUID has value NULL.

How do I specify this condtion?

```
select tsearch.Description,

tcompany.CompanyName,
tcompany.GUID as CompanyGuid,
tcompanylocation.LocationName,
tsearchtype.SearchType,
tsearchresult.searchresult,
tpeople.GUID as PersonPlacedGuid,
tpeople.LastName As PersonPlacedLName,
tpeople.Firstname As PersonPlacedFName,
tsearch.SearchNotes,
( select tpeople.Firstname  from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.RepresentativeGUID) as repfirstname, 
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.RepresentativeGUID) as replastname,
tsearch.RepresentativeGUID as RepGuid,
tposition.Position as backgroundposition,
tdepartment.Department as backgrounddepartment,
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.ReferredByGUID) as referredbylastname,
( select tpeople.FirstName from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.ReferredByGUID) as referredbylastname,
tsearch.ReferredByGUID as PersonwhorefferedGuid,
( select tcompany.CompanyName from tCompany where tCompany.guid=tSearch.PlacedFromGUID) as placedfrom,
tinstantstatustype.InstantStatus,
tWorkbench.WorkbenchName,
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tInstantStatus.PeopleGUID) as Candlastname,
( select tpeople.FirstName from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tInstantStatus.PeopleGUID) as candFirstname,
tInstantStatus.ForClientNotes,
tinstantstatus.InstantStatusNotes as InstanttatusNotesSummary,
tAttributes.Attribute as Attributes,
a1.Attribute as Categories


from tSearch


full join tCompany on tsearch.CompanyGUID = tcompany.guid
full join tcompanylocation on tcompanylocation.guid= tcompany.LocationGUID
full join tSearchType on tsearchtype.GUID = tSearch.SearchTypeGUID
full join tSearchResult on tSearchResult.GUID = tsearch.SearchResultGUID
full join tPeople on tPeople.GUID = tsearch.PlacedGUID
full join tPosition on tPosition.GUID = tsearch.PositionGUID
full join tDepartment on tdepartment.GUID = tsearch.DepartmentGUID
full join tInstantStatus on tInstantStatus.SearchGUID = tSearch.guid
full join tInstantStatusType on tInstantStatusType.GUID = tInstantStatus.InstantStatusGUID 
full join tWorkbench on tWorkbench.SearchGUID=tsearch.GUID
full join tSearchCluendex on tSearchCluendex.CPSGUID=tsearch.GUID
full join tAttributes on tAttributes.GUID=tSearchCluendex.AttributeGUID
LEFT JOIN tAttributes AS a1 ON a1.GUID=tSearchCluendex.AttributeGUID
```

**Update 3:**

```
select * from tAttributes where RelatedGUID is null;
```

List 11 categories, entries that have RelatedGUID as NULL.

Now when I try as suggested by @iamdave solution:

```
select tsearch.Description,

tcompany.CompanyName,
tcompany.GUID as CompanyGuid,
tcompanylocation.LocationName,
tsearchtype.SearchType,
tsearchresult.searchresult,
tpeople.GUID as PersonPlacedGuid,
tpeople.LastName As PersonPlacedLName,
tpeople.Firstname As PersonPlacedFName,
tsearch.SearchNotes,
( select tpeople.Firstname  from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.RepresentativeGUID) as repfirstname, 
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.RepresentativeGUID) as replastname,
tsearch.RepresentativeGUID as RepGuid,
tposition.Position as backgroundposition,
tdepartment.Department as backgrounddepartment,
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.ReferredByGUID) as referredbylastname,
( select tpeople.FirstName from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tSearch.ReferredByGUID) as referredbylastname,
tsearch.ReferredByGUID as PersonwhorefferedGuid,
( select tcompany.CompanyName from tCompany where tCompany.guid=tSearch.PlacedFromGUID) as placedfrom,
tinstantstatustype.InstantStatus,
tWorkbench.WorkbenchName,
( select tpeople.Lastname from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tInstantStatus.PeopleGUID) as Candlastname,
( select tpeople.FirstName from tpeople where tpeople.guid=tInstantStatus.PeopleGUID) as candFirstname,
tInstantStatus.ForClientNotes,
tinstantstatus.InstantStatusNotes as InstanttatusNotesSummary,
a1.Attribute as Attributes,
a2.Attribute as Categories


from tSearch


full join tCompany on tsearch.CompanyGUID = tcompany.guid
full join tcompanylocation on tcompanylocation.guid= tcompany.LocationGUID
full join tSearchType on tsearchtype.GUID = tSearch.SearchTypeGUID
full join tSearchResult on tSearchResult.GUID = tsearch.SearchResultGUID
full join tPeople on tPeople.GUID = tsearch.PlacedGUID
full join tPosition on tPosition.GUID = tsearch.PositionGUID
full join tDepartment on tdepartment.GUID = tsearch.DepartmentGUID
full join tInstantStatus on tInstantStatus.SearchGUID = tSearch.guid
full join tInstantStatusType on tInstantStatusType.GUID = tInstantStatus.InstantStatusGUID 
full join tWorkbench on tWorkbench.SearchGUID=tsearch.GUID
full join tSearchCluendex on tSearchCluendex.CPSGUID=tsearch.GUID 
full join tAttributes AS a1 ON a1.GUID=tSearchCluendex.AttributeGUID and a1.RelatedGUID is not NULL
full join tAttributes AS a2 ON a2.GUID=tSearchCluendex.AttributeGUID and a2.RelatedGUID is NULL
```

It returns output like below:

i.e

```
...    Attribute  |  Category

...    NULL       |  NULL
...    Programmer |  NULL
...    Secretary  |  NULL
...    Manager    |  NULL
```

where "Programmer" should be in "IT" Category, "Secretary" in "Biz Dev" etc. So the Attributes are OK, but Categories are not looked up, despite the JOIN and condition being there ....

This database is pretty big, ca 40 tables, so it is hard for me to paste SQL structure, but hopefully some smart and good soul will get the point. If not please, let me know what should I paste (please specify commands to execute in MS SSMS)

Thanks,

Comment: If you expect more than one result you must use a `JOIN` for this. But you will get repeated rows...

Comment: Repeated rows are ok, as long as I have attributes and categories columns that match to each other. How to do it? Thanks!

Comment: @android_dev - you need to correlate your `sub-query`

Comment: What is `tAttributes.RelatedGUID`? If this is pointing to a GUID of your resultset, just add a `LEFT JOIN` and use this value in the `ON`-clause

Comment: One more hint: If you are using the same table more often in joins you have to use a name-alias. Somethink like `LEFT JOIN tAttributes AS a1 ON a1.RelatedGUID=Someother.GUID`. And in your select list you get the value with `a1.Attribute`. The next occurance call "a2" and so on...

Comment: Thanks for all the hints! I am a beginner to SQL Server and TSQL, so I am not sure I understand all of this. I am kind of "learning by doing", can somebody adjust my query so I can get the point and learn it for the future? I just want to add Attributes and Categories columns to ouput, Attirbutes have RelatedGUID not NULL and Categories have it NULL.

Comment: @Shnugo I tried your hint, but no luck :( See "Update 1"

Comment: @android_dev, try to replace your `( select a1.Attribute ....` just with `at.Attribute`. No need for a sub-select there...

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks. See my Update 2. Looks better. But how do I specify my condition, Attributes should show only rows when RelatedGUID is not NULL and Categories where it is NULL. Thats why I used sub-select in the first place ...

Comment: Your query looks like it is vastly over complicating things, but without source schema and data this is impossible to tell.  Can you please post some `create table` scripts along with some `insert` statements to populate them and a desired output?

Comment: But in answer to your question on filtering the rows returned in your `join`s, you can simply add the condition into your `on` statement, for example `ON a1.GUID = tSearchCluendex.AttributeGUID and a1.RelatedGUID is not null`

Comment: Thanks!!! Thought it would solve it, but unfortunately not. See my Update 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` statements should do the trick. Instead of looking for records where null or not null, the idea is to check the values in each record and proceed accordingly.  Something like:

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN tAttributes.RelatedGUID is not null then tAttributes.Attribute ELSE null END) as Attributes,
(CASE WHEN tAttributes.RelatedGUID is null then tAttributes.Attribute ELSE null END) as Categories
FROM tAttributes
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Nice idea .... I am checking my dataset, but it seems to be doing what it is supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

Add Condition in where and using CASE .. WHEN .. THEN.. TRY TO FOLLOWING WAY..

select col1,col2,...colN..from Table Where clm1 = CASE WHEN @PARAMETER = 0 THEN COL1 ELSE @PARAMETER

ONCE YOU SET SAME COLUMN NAME INTO WHERE CONDITION THEN YOU RETRIEVE ALL DATA FROM TABLE ELSE IF YOU WANT TO PASS AS PARAMETER THEN RETRIEVE BASE ON CONDITION VALUES FROM TABLE.